# For what reason, RequestDispatcher.forward() method returns to the calling servlet? What's the use of returning, if we can't make changes in response?

Tags: java, servlets, requestdispatcher

I just want to understand the purpose behind returning back to the calling servlet, after the execution of forwarded servlet.

Below example simply shows that after execution of forwarded servlet, control returns back to calling servlet.

```
//servlet1 Code (Forwarding to servlet2)   
@WebServlet("/servlet1")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

      RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("servlet2");
      rd.forward(request, response);

      System.out.println("Returned to Calling Servlet");
   }
}

//servlet2 Code (returning control to servlet1)  
@WebServlet("/servlet2")
public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String n = "to Servlet2";
    out.print("Welcome " + n);
   }
}
```

#### Output ::

Welcome to Servlet2 (on Browser)

Returned to Calling Servlet (on Console)

#### Need clarification :

After committing response, why it's returning back to **servlet1**

Comment: Because that's how method invocation works. You call method `forward()`. When it completes, execution returns to the caller.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : Then why sendRedirect() method doesn't return. I want to know the purpose for making it return to calling Servlet. What's the use of this design?

Comment: Of course it returns, you can execute other methods after invoking `sendRedirect(...)`.

Comment: [Servlet Chaining and Filtering](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch02_05.htm)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yeah, I got that. But, out of curiosity I want to understand, why isn't there a way just forward/redirect, without returning to calling servlet? Is it serving any purpose?

Comment: I've never tried this, but since the `forward` and `sendRedirect` methods return control to the caller, perhaps the caller can both redirect and forward the request or forward to multiple locations.